# Add pipeline phase change to activity report

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm using Dynamics 365 and want to figure out how to customise the activity report to include changes to the current pipeline phase of an opportunity

eg. Opportunity A is moved from Qualify > Develop

Currently I can only set it to capture when an opportunity has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

To modify system report you will have to export its definition as *.rdl file (“Download report” menu option), edit rdl file in some code editor (for example Visual Studio Data Tools) and reimport it to CRM. This operation will require some knowledge regarding SQL Server Reporting Services report schema and knowledge about querying CRM database.

Because modifying system reports may be little painful my recommendation is building new report (similar to existing one) which will meet all your business requirements.